# how to solve this non-linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$h$ is a smooth function of $r$, how to solve for general solutions of $rh''+h'(1+(h')^2)=0$? (This is deduced from pde of minimal surface problem.)

Comment: Rearrange as -1/r = h''/(h'(1+(h')^2)). Now integrate. The rhs essentially requires you to be able to integrate 1/(x(1+x^2)). That is easier than it looks. Just use partial fractions: 1/x - x/(1+x^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
Set h'(r)=f(r) and solve the 1st order ODE for f(r), which is separable and trivial to solve.

Alternatively, plug it to Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha...

Answer (score 1):

Separate variables and integrate:
$$ \frac{1}{r} = -\frac{h''}{h'(1+h'^2)}= h'' \left( -\frac{1}{h'}+\frac{h'}{1+h'^2} \right), $$
and integrating gives
$$ \log{r}+\log{a} = \log{\left( \frac{\sqrt{1+h'^2}}{h'} \right)}. $$
Exponentiating and rearranging,
$$ h' = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2r^2-1}}, $$
which has antiderivative
$$ h = C \pm \frac{1}{a} \arg\cosh{ar}, $$
by substituting $r=a^{-1}\cosh{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$ r h ^{''} + h ' ( 1+ h^{'2}) =  0 \tag{1} $$

or

$$\frac{ r h ^{''}} {  h ' ( 1+ h^{'2})} =  -1\tag{2} $$

Instead of h a function of r , we interchange axes $ r \leftrightarrow h $ so that r is a function of h. With this transformation of axes as applicable to inverse functions

$$ h' \rightarrow \frac{1}{r'} ; h'' \rightarrow \frac{r''}{r'^3} \tag{3}$$

we can incorporate change of differentials :

(3) simplifies to

$$  \frac {rr''}{1+r'^2} = -1 \tag{4}$$

which has no $h$ as independent variable .It is same as

$$  \frac{r'' r \sqrt{(1+r'^2)} }{(1+r'^2)^{3/2}} = -1 \tag{5}$$

This can be recognized as the radius of curvature and normal up to x-axis

$$ \frac{R_2}{R_1} = -1  \tag{6} $$

which is a property of the catenary.

But it can also be got by direct integration with substitution

$$ \dfrac{dr}{dz} = \tan \phi \tag{7} $$

as,

$$ r  \cos \phi = c \tag{8} $$

and finally as:

$$ r = c \cosh \left( \frac{z- c_1}{c} \right) \tag{9}  $$